# Join and Display 2 Columns from One Table refer by Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table

Columns inside **table_A** : data, id_A, id_B, status

[image]

Columns inside **table_B** : id, username

[image]

I want to display username from table_B reference from columns inside table_A (id_A & id_B) and make the alias id_A as User_1 and id_B as User_2

I has been working with INNER JOIN but it still make me confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this...

```
SELECT a.username as User_1, b.username as User_2 FROM
table_A t
JOIN table_B b on b.id = t.id_B
JOIN table_B a ON a.id = t.id_A
```